# Sub query and GroupBy in Azure cosmosDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a situation where i need to get container item based on a GroupBy sub query. This looks simple but not working for me. Help is appreciated! Below is the sql query

```
SELECT * FROM my_container 
WHERE my_container.item.Id 
IN (SELECT VALUE c.item.Id FROM c WHERE c.item.name = 'ABC'
    GROUP BY c.item.Id )
```

*Gives error as it is not in correct IN acceptable format*. `IN ('a', 'b')`

My my_container items are something like:

```
[
  {
    item : {
        name: "ABC",
        id: "1",
        address1: "address1",
        city: "city1"
    },
    item : {
        name: "ABC",
        id: "2",
        address1: "address2",
        city: "city2"
    },
    item : {
        name: "ABC",
        id: "3",
        address1: "address3",
        city: "city3"
    },
  }
]
```

Comment: what is the actual error

Comment: Hi Sajeetharan, Error is "incorrect syntax near Select...." as it gives in Azure output window. When i pass in string it runs fine like SELECT * FROM my_container 
WHERE my_container.item.Id 
IN ('ABC', 'XYZ'); But using subquery it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The result of your sub query is an array[],but keyword `IN` just supports ().
I tried this sql:

`SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS((SELECT VALUE c.item.id FROM c WHERE c.item.name = 'ABC' GROUP BY c.item.id),c.item.id,false)`

But it gets 0 rows.The reason is that ARRAY_CONTAINS() function does not support sub query as argument.
AS a workaround:
you should use 2 sqls to achieve the goal.

First,execute the sql `SELECT VALUE c.item.id FROM c WHERE c.item.name = 'ABC' GROUP BY c.item.id` to get the outputs array[].

Then,pass the result you get at the first step to ARRAY_CONTAINS() and execute the below sql

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(['1','2','3'],c.item.id,false)
```

By the way,sub query in cosmos db unlike the relation database's.Learn more about sub query,please refer to this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/sql-query-subquery).

Comment: For future reference, watch out as false is not the same as FALSE. CosmosDB seems to be case sensitive.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Steve's answer, you can call ARRAY function on your subquery, instead of copying & pasting query result. Like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM c WHERE ARRAY_CONTAINS(
        ARRAY(SELECT VALUE c.item.id FROM c WHERE c.item.name = 'ABC' GROUP BY c.item.id),
        c.item.id,
        false
    )
```